# How to move a StreamBlock between apps

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm refactoring some code and I wish to move a custom StreamBlock (or StructBlock) from one django app to another.

This seems like it would be **much** simpler than migrating tables between apps.

1. Move the block declarations to the new app
2. Update any dependencies to point to new module
3. Update old migration files (imports, etc) to point to new app
4. ... PROFIT

Is this really all we need to do? Are there any deployment risks, here - or is this really a **pure python** change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the block declaration itself doesn't change, and all StreamFields referencing it are updated to point to it in its new location - yes, it's a pure Python change. You don't even need to update migrations, because migrations are set up to include their own frozen copy of `StreamBlock` / `StructBlock` definitions as they existed at the time of creation, rather than pointing to the definition within your app code.

Comment: Thank you! Most of my stream deconstructs into the base types, but I am hitting the caveat where this doesn't hold true. I forget where I read it (probably github) where things like overloading constructors can cause this effect.

Comment: I guess you mean the note here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#streamfield-definitions-within-migrations